# using className instead of class breaks CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm currently implementing a Swiper using react. I'm using Bullets as pagination marks. My code for the pagination looks as follows:

```
<Swiper
                    navigation
                    pagination={{
                        clickable: true,
                        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
                            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                        }
                    }}
                    onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                    onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                >
```

Since I'm using react the attribute of the span should be className instead of class. The problem is, that if I change it to className instead of class, the CSS of the bullets does not get applied. I hope somebody can help me to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: @nouvist done, I'm sorry.

Comment: why are you returning a string?

Comment: You should use `className` in JSX. The `renderBullet` function returns a HTML string.

Comment: Does the bullet need to be stringified HTML, or can it be JSX?

Comment: @DrewReese [Looks like it has to be a HTML string](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/49e06f9f35aecae1a002bdec679dae6d6aaebb01/src/components/pagination/pagination.js#L217).

Comment: I've got the function from the docs, I tried using JSX instead but it only returns an object then. So I think it's got to be stringified HTML. Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you try  ` <span class=${className}>' + (index + 1) + '</span> `

Comment: @miraj This still gives me the error to use className instead of class unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure that is where your error is? Can you share the actual error message in your question? I'm assuming there is an accompanying stacktrace as well.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I'm sure this is where the error sits. The actual error message is just the typical "Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?" when using "class" in the span element. When using className instead(as usual for jsx), the css does not get applied to the element.

Comment: I'm just doubting that since *that* span isn't JSX, far from it. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect live and debug?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the span is not JSX, it's an HTML string, since this is what it has to be for the swiper. Arun Kumar Mohan already linked the source of how it gets processed in a link above. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
return <span className={`${className}`}>{index + 1}</span>;
```

This will work!

Comment: It won't work. [The `renderBullet` function is expected to return a HTML string](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/49e06f9f35aecae1a002bdec679dae6d6aaebb01/src/components/pagination/pagination.js#L217).

Comment: I tried it before already and it doesn't work like that unfortunately. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @Steven If your function only expects HTML string and not JSX element then you can only use class, you will get a warning in React though, but you can ignore that. Or you can try to customize the swiper pagination outside the swiper component and take active index from functions that are mostly available in libraries.

Comment: @RohitKhandelwal Alright, in this case I will just leave it like that, thanks a lot. Do you know if there's a way to suppress the error at this specific place though? Driving me crazy to see red in my console.